# Heroku + S3 + Django: Static Files not Cached

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

Currently have a project deployed on Heroku with static files loaded from S3. I'm using boto/django-storage to manage my S3 content, but if I call the same view or load the same page repeatedly, all the images/static content load twice and is not cached.

I've placed 
`AWS_HEADERS = {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=2592000',
    }`

in my `settings.py`, but the reason seems the same exact images (refreshed + loaded twice) have different signatures in their URL? I've tried multiples headers, but the browser doesn't seem want to cache it and instead loads them all everytime.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`. Then the URL generated will always be the same (public) URL. The default-ACL in `S3BotoStorage`is `public-read`, which shouldn't be changed then.

Two things not to forget:

- perhaps you want to add `public, max-age=XXX`, so public proxies also can cache your content?
- When you want the browser to cache that long, you should keep in mind that the filenames have to change when you change the content. One solution would be to `S3BotoStorage` combined with the Django-`CachedStaticFilesStorage` (see [here](http://peterman.is/blog/amazon-s3-and-djangos-cachedstaticfilesstorage/2012/10/), but I use it without the seperate cache-backend)